# How to Force HTTPS Google Maps Android API V1 & V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have spent a while researching this through Google and Stackoverflow but have come up dry. I have also reviewed the API reference for both versions  I am trying to find out if the Google Maps Android API can be forced to use https instead of http. We have a request from one of our clients to restrict the requests to https based on a third party security report of our app. If this is possible we would like to integrate it into apps for our other clients as well.

The reason I am needing it for both versions is that we have clients on both maps v1 and v2.  The ones on v1 cannot be converted to version 2 for the immediate future.

I would like to find some kind of reference that either confirms the ability or states that it can not be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to find some kind of reference that either confirms the ability or states that it can not be done.

It is impossible to prove a negative. However:

- You cannot modify the source code to Maps V1 or Maps V2, because we do not have that source code
- There is no API to control anything regarding the networking aspects of Maps V1 or Maps V2, as you can tell by reading the documentation for those APIs
- For Maps V2 at least, the actual networking is done by another app (Play Services Framework) in another process, AFAICT, and you have no way of modifying the behavior of that app
- If Google is not using HTTPS today for Maps V1/V2 map tiles, it is well within reason that Google never uses HTTPS for Maps V1/V2 map tiles (you could attempt to modify some firewall settings on your local network to see if HTTPS is an option, by blocking the HTTP URLs you find via packet sniffing, to see if Google fails over to using HTTPS URLs)

The onus is on the security auditor to demonstrate that what they want is possible. If *they* do not have some documented and supported means of forcing Maps V1/V2 to use HTTPS, then they are being unethical for suggesting that other apps are insecure due to the behavior of Maps V1/V2. They may as well claim that your app is insecure because it is incapable of raising the dead, or incapable of transmuting lead into gold, or any number of other seemingly impossible tasks.

Comment: Yes great answer and exactly what I was looking for.  Their position on HTTPS was that the web based API could do it.  They also stated that the API key was not required which indicated to me they were not familiar with the Google Map Android api to begin with.  Aware can't prove negative but was hoping that I missed it somewhere in the API ref or FAQ stating that it couldn't be done.  +1

Comment: @GeorgeBaker: "which indicated to me they were not familiar with the Google Map Android api to begin with" -- it certainly sounds as if that is the case.